# Test case in groovy failing while migrating from java 11 to 17

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, migration, java-17

I am getting this error when I am updating java version from 11 to 17.

```
SpecInternals.SpyImpl:168->SpecInternals.createMockImpl:295->SpecInternals.createMockImpl:305-   
>SpecInternals.createMock:50 » NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class 
org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CglibMockFactory$ConstructorFriendlyEnhancer
```

I updated to following versions:

- spock - 2.3-groovy-3.0
- groovy-all - 3.0.19
- gmavenplus-plugin - 3.0.2
- maven-surefire-plugin - 3.2.2
- cglib-nodep.version - 3.2.9
- maven-compiler-plugin - 3.9.0
- jacoco-maven-plugin - 0.8.10

But I am still facing the issue. Please let me know if anyone has come across this error while migrating from java 11 to 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem; I replaced `cglib-nodep` by `byte-buddy`, then the error disappeared.